# LWC datatable Sorry to interrupt Error

Tags: lightning-web-components

accountExcelImport.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account Data Import" variant="Narrow">
        <lightning-button variant="Neutral" label="Data Import" onclick={opModal} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        <template if:true={accounts.length}>
            
        </template>
        <template if:false={accounts.length}>
            <div style="text-align: center;" class="no-data-message">No data available.</div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
    <template if:true={ModalOpen}>
        <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC starts here -->
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC header here -->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={cloModal}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                            alternative-text="close"
                            variant="inverse"
                            size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Data Import</h2>
                </header>
                <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC body starts here -->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" style="text-align: center;" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <template if:true={accounts.length}>
                        <lightning-datatable
                            key-field="Id"
                            data={accounts}
                            columns={columns}
                            hide-checkbox-column="true">
                        </lightning-datatable>
                    </template>
                    <template if:false={accounts.length}>
                        <div style="text-align: center;" class="no-data-message" onpaste={pasteData}>Excel Data Ctrl + V</div>
                    </template>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC footer starts here -->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={cloModal} title="Cancel">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={subDetail} title="Submit">Submit</button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
</template>
```

accountExcelImport.js

```
import { LightningElement,track,wire,api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class AccountConvertButton extends LightningElement {
    @track ModalOpen = false;
    @api recordId;
    @track accounts = [];
    @track columns = [];
    
    opModal() {
        this.ModalOpen = true;
    }

    cloModal() {
        this.ModalOpen = false;
        this.accounts = [];
    }

    subDetail() {
        this.ModalOpen = false;
        this.accounts = [];
    }
    
    pasteData(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const pastedData = event.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        const rows = pastedData.split('\n');
        const col = rows[0].split('\t');
    
        const data = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
            const rowData = rows[i].split('\t');
            const rowObject = {};
            for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                rowObject[col[j]] = rowData[j];
            }
            data.push(rowObject);
        }
        
        this.columns = col.map((col) => ({
            label: col,
            fieldName: col,
            editable: false
        }));
        this.accounts = data;
    }    

    showTst(title, message, variant) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I am currently working on implementing a feature in an LWC component where a modal window is opened, and I'm using the onpaste event in a  to automatically insert data copied from Excel into a datatable. While the data insertion into the datatable works well, I'm encountering an error when clicking on the last column of the datatable. How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: Can you add to your question what's in the last column of the data table like a button, checkbox, or something that handles an event in the js file? another question in the "LWC data table Sorry to interrupt Error" is there any detail about the error, I suggest checking if you get any console error in your browser devtools window.

Comment: are you using release org? Can you check which api version is available in your org?